# Keeps saying I have to add unimplemented methods

Tags: java

```
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;


/**
 * VolunteerLine Interface represents the interface for the VolunteerLine Class

* The class that uses this  interface uses a Queue of Volunteers to simulate queuing and dequeuing volunteers to and from the 
* VolunteerLine.
* @author khandan Monshi
*
*/

public interface VolunteerLineInterface {

    /**
     * adds a new Volunteer to the volunteer line Queue
     * @param v A Volunteer object
     * @return true if volunteer is queued successfully , false if queue is full
     */
    public boolean  addNewVoluneer(Volunteer v);

    /**
     * removes volunteer from the volunteer queue line
     * @return Volunteer Object
     * @throws NoSuchElementException if queue is empty
     */
    public  Volunteer volunteerTurn () throws NoSuchElementException;

    /**
     * checks if there are volunteers in line 
     * @return true if volunteer line is empty, true otherwise
     */
    public boolean volunteerLineEmpty();
    /**
     * Returns an array of the Volunteers in the queue
     * @return an array of the volunteers in the queue
     */
    public Volunteer[] toArrayVolunteer();

}
```

---

```
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class VolunteerLine implements VolunteerLineInterface{




    @Override
    public boolean addNewVoluneer(Volunteer v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            return false; 


    }

    @Override
    public Volunteer volunteerTurn() throws NoSuchElementException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean volunteerLineEmpty() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            return false;    

    }

    @Override
    public Volunteer[] toArrayVolunteer() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Im not done with this yet, I still have other errors I need to fix, But the problem I'm having is I keep getting an error saying: "The type VolunteerLine must implement the inherited abstract method VolunteerLineInterface.addNewVoluneer(Volunteer)" Even though I clearly have it implemented. I have an error on the VolunteerLine and when I hover my mouse over it and click add unimplemented methods, it still shows up saying the same errors. Is there something that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try fixing the other errors and come back to this. You might just need a clean build.

Comment: I notice a typo in your method name: addNewVoluneer (missing letter 't')

Comment: Compiles fine for me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the code does ***not*** yield the error that the OP is complaining about.

Comment: The "error" is due to a typo (or an independent error), so I am voting to close too.

Comment: The typo is in both though.

Answer (score 2):

Just fix the other compilation errors and do a clean build. Your implementation of abstract method as posted by you are fine.